# How can I test a Scala 3 compiler plugin in the same project?

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

I have a project that is a Scala 3 plugin.  Right now I publishLocal and run another project that imports my plugin for every test.  Not very convenient.

How can I set up my plugin project so I can test my code in the same project (the plugin project)?

Comment: Haven't tried it on Scala 3, but the [old way](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for/blob/9c0062f752c8128525da895cb3339e9e506b8387/build.sbt#L15) with setting a scalac parameter would still work. You don't even need a subproject, just set the option in Test scope.

Comment: Which parameter?

Comment: `-Xplugin`. [Kind-projector plugin build](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector/blob/main/build.sbt#L123) is probably the closest to what you want